# Keep leading and trailing islands of True in a boolean array - NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Given i have this 1d-numpy array.

```
a = np.array([True True True False False False False True True False True False False False False False False True True])
```

Expeceted result:

```
b = np.array([True True True False False False False False False False False False False False False False False True True])
```

EDITED for clarity:
How do i (1) keep the "island" of True values in the leading and trailing positions of the 1d array while (2) converting all other True values to False for True values that are not in the leading or trailing "island" of the 1d array?

I have tried the obvious non-efficient answer, that is to iterate naively through it, but i can't help but feel that there is a better solution. Anyone has a better idea?

Thanks for reading!!! :)

Comment: Could add an expected output?

Comment: Can you have False value terminating or starting the sequence?

Comment: If you have a working solution and want a critique, you could post your solution @ codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is your definition of a sequence? The whole `a` or a slice of `a` that consists of all `True`s?

Comment: Added expected output! @ViníciusAguiar

Comment: Your second `True` is not in a leading or trailing position, why is it still `True` in the expected output?

Comment: @DYZ I am guessing because its still in the first "island" of True values.

Comment: @Divakar Let's not guess but wait for the OPs clarification. The definition of a sequence is still not clear.

Comment: @snowflake Clarify on the definition of "sequence" here? I am guessing its the "island" of True values. [From your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114237/numpy-boolean-array-manipulation-of-non-leading-or-trailing-values#comment77199954_45114312), that's what I could gather.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. @Divakar is right, it is the first "island" in the trailing and leading position of the 1d-array (sequence) should be preserved.

Comment: @snowflake Please add that comment into the question for the other people confused about it. Also comments get deleted. So, its better suited in the question.

Comment: @Divakar Done! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Please clarify what happens in the case of `[True False True True False]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one approach making use of [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) and [`numpy.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) to detect the island start and stop indices -

```
def fill_inner_islands(a):
    acc = np.maximum.accumulate
    start = a.argmax()
    end = a.size-a[::-1].argmax()
    a0 = ~a[start:end]
    a[start:end] = ~(acc(a0) & acc(a0[::-1])[::-1])
```

Sample runs -

Case #1 :

```
In [140]: a.astype(int)
Out[140]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

In [141]: fill_inner_islands(a)

In [142]: a.astype(int)
Out[142]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Case #2 :

```
In [144]: a.astype(int)
Out[144]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [145]: fill_inner_islands(a)

In [146]: a.astype(int)
Out[146]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Case #3 :

```
In [148]: a.astype(int)
Out[148]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])

In [149]: fill_inner_islands(a)

In [150]: a.astype(int)
Out[150]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

**Approach #2**

Simpler approach -

```
def fill_inner_islands_v2(a):
    # Get stop and end indices of leading and trailing islands.
    # We do this by using one-off shifted slices and looking for the fall
    # in forward direction and fall in flipped direction   
    start = (a[1:] < a[:-1]).argmax()+1
    end = a.size - 1 - (a[:-1][::-1] < a[1:][::-1]).argmax()

    # Get the slice within those indices and assign as all False
    if ~a[start:end].all(): # To handle all True in input array
        a[start:end] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Thats some wizardry, will look through your implementation carefully!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
       False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Assume the array starts and ends with True; find the True-False, False-True breaks with np.diff

```
>>> b = np.diff(a)
>>> b
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,
        True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Find the indices of those breaks with np.where

```
>>> c = np.where(b)
>>> c = c[0]
>>> c
array([ 2,  6,  8,  9, 10, 16], dtype=int64)
>>>
>>> # c = b.nonzero()[0]
```

Again, Assume the array starts and ends with True - you only care about the first and last break

```
>>> x, y = c[0], c[-1]
>>> x, y
(2, 16)
>>>
```

Use those indices on the left-hand-side of an assignment

```
 >>> a[x+1:y] = False
>>> a
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! It is useful!

Answer (score 0):

I came with the following solution for you, it intends to quickly go to set `False` to all data, and restores values after that. I don't know if that's faster than iterating over each value, due to instanciation of a numpy array, but that's a different approach which does not change content of `a` and does no loop.

```
a = np.array([True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True])

b = np.array([False] * len(a))
b[0] = a[0]; b[-1] = a[-1]
```

**Update following your feedback:**

This is ugly, but makes no loop so you might find it interesting for large sets of True/False values. Note that the array here is not a numpy array.

```
a = [True, True, True, False, False, True]
start = a.index(False)
a.reverse()
end = a.index(False) * -1
a.reverse()

result = a[:start] + [False] * (len(a) - (start + end * -1)) + a[end:]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. But i would still like to preserve the leading and trailing True values in the sequence, not just one at both the head and tail.

Comment: I realised that it's because of my poor phrasing that resulted in you misunderstanding my question! So sorry about that!!

Answer (score 0):

Any solution to this problem involves iterations. Here's one that does not have any explicit loops:

```
b = a.tolist()
start = b.index(False)
end = b[::-1].index(False)
if end:
    a[start : -end] = False
else:
    a[start : ] = False
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with this : `array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])`.

Comment: @Divakar Why, `array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`. All leading 1s are in place, and since there are no trailing 1s, none of them is preserved.

Comment: Should be : `array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])` based on OP's clarifications.

Comment: @Divakar The latter two 1s are not in the trailing positions.

Comment: The latter two elements (True) are in latter island of True values. OP is working with islands.

Comment: @Divakar The OP is working with the islands in the leading or trailing positions. The second island in your example is not in the trailing position.

Comment: The second and third islands are not in leading or trailing positions. That's why they should be removed. But the fourth(last) island is the trailing island, so both of its elements must be kept.